# Double quotes issue in retrieving value from json object

Tags: json, scala, spray-json

I am using `Spray json` and converting `http response` to json object in following way and fetching value of `WebId` key from it:

```
val json = http_response.body.parseJson
val web_id = json.asJsObject().getFields("WebId")
println(web_id(0))
```

The output of `http_response.body` is : `{"WebId":"F1AbETkR"}`

the output of `println` is : `"F1AbETkR"`

The issue is `web_id` is coming in form of string with `double quotes` included which when concatenated in another `http uri` results in improper url formation.

It can be solved by simply stripping double quotes from beginning and end but Is there a better/easier/cleaner way of direct fetching of value without double quotes?

Comment: Could you put an example of the json? If I understand correctly and the double quotes are part of the WebId value, then I guess you need to strip them afterwards.

Comment: Ok, so it should work. I think the issue is that the type of the web_id in that code is not String, but some spray_json jsValue wrapper like JsString and when you try to print it, it's actually calling that classes toString() that formats it with quotes. Try something like: val webId: String = web_id(0).convertTo[String]

Comment: @PietariKettunen web_id is `Seq[JsValue]`

Comment: The error is `Error:(54, 30) not enough arguments for method convertTo: (implicit evidence$1: spray.json.JsonReader[String])String.
Unspecified value parameter evidence$1.
    print(web_id(0).convertTo[String])`

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you are trying to "print" the `JsValue` which is giving you these extra double-quotes, you need to convert the `JsValue` to `String`.

```
import spray.json._
// following import will provide implicit readers for `String` type
import DefaultJsonProtocol._

val jsonString = """{"WebId":"F1AbETkR"}"""

val webId = jsonString.parseJson.asJsObject.getFields("WebId")(0).convertTo[String]
// webId: String = F1AbETkR
```